# error handling in Swift 2

Tags: error-handling, swift2, xcode7, uiimagepngrepresentation

i have to fix the follow code for swift2.

```
if !UIImagePNGRepresentation(img).writeToFile(imagePath, options: nil, error: &error) {
                        if let actualError = error {
                            NSLog("Image not saved. \(actualError)")
                        }
                    }
```

To compile it i have this error on `if row: Cannot invoke writeToFile` with an argument list of type `(String, options: _, error: inout NSError?)`

How I can fix it.

Comment: For future questions, try to make the title as relevant to the problem as possible. Most users don't have time to click on a vague question and solve a vague problem. This will result in your question not receiving a lot of traffic and you not getting your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it with

```
UIImagePNGRepresentation(img)?.writeToFile(imagePath, atomically: true)
```

instead. Check the [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSData_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSData/writeToFile:atomically:).

**Edit:**

To answer your question more precisely use the [error handling in Swift 2](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ErrorHandling.html).

```
do {
    try UIImagePNGRepresentation(img)?.writeToFile(imagePath, options: .DataWritingAtomic)
} catch let error as NSError {
    print("Image not saved. \(error.description)")
}
```

Comment: I'm glad! Please mark my answer as correct than. (Little checkmark beneath the counter on the left.) Thanks.